# How to pass an array of primitives as Request in Postman

Tags: java, spring, request

I was wondering what is the best way to pass a simple int[] array to a Spring Controller?

As of now it only worked when I am passing the values as a @RequestParam in the URL, however I would like to send them for example as a @RequestBody. How could I do that?

`

```
@PostMapping
public int acceptArray(@RequestParam int[] array) {

    if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "You entered an empty array");
    }

    return arraySolver.arraySolver(array);
}
```

`

Since I am kinda new a more detailed explanation would be appreciated :)

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: like this [
    1,
    3,
    4,
    5
]   you just put this as the body for the RequestBody

Comment: @Anon I think requirement here is to pass it though request param not through request body.

Comment: @KunalVarpe he as RequestParam in code but he wants to change it to RequestBody just read the second paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by passing the multiple arguments as query params like show in below. The controller is taking array as input and sum the elements and returns that. That is why for [1,2,3] it outputs 6.

[image]

To send it as request body you can just follow below code.

```java
@PostMapping
    public int acceptArray(@RequestBody InputArrayRequest request) {

        if (request.getArray() == null || request.getArray().length == 0) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "You entered an empty array()");
        }

        return arraySolver.arraySolver(array);
    }

class InputArrayRequest {
    private int[] array;

    public int[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the wrapper class did the job and I guess this would be also considered better practise, right? One more question related to the comment below from Nithish Subramaniyan. How can I tell my method to accept form data instead of JSON for example?

Comment: The request body approach from above code will accept JSON as body

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array by specifying the same key multiple times in `Body` > `form-data` like in this screenshot:
[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. I tried what is shown on the screenshot, however I get the 415 Status with error: Unsupported media type. Here is the screenshot : https://ibb.co/q1NFgqn

Comment: As stated all I want to receive is just a int[] with numbers in :) and maybe an explanation of how to do the same for Strings would also be nice if there is something different there.

Comment: Hello, I need more details. Why you want to use only primitive datatype only. why not JSON or XML

Answer (score 0):

if you want an array of ints from a RequestBody

[image]

```
@PostMapping
public int acceptArray(@RequestBody int[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "You entered an empty array()");
    }
    return Arrays.stream(array).sum();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response kind sir <3 I am so happy that one of my first questions here got answered so fast. You are amazing guys!